# can I use www as a cname for cloudfront domain if my domain already redirects to www

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cname

I'm trying to use cloudfront on my whole web site, but I want to use my domain name instead of the cloudfront one.

Currently (before cloudfront) all request to my domain example.com are redirected by code to www.example.com. On my DNS the CNAME www.example.com has a value of example.com.

Now that I have configure cloudfront and have their domain (example1234.cludfront.com).

Do the only thing I need to do is, change the value of the CNAME www.example.com to example1234.cludfront.com? And I will be using cludfront with my domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although you might need to configure the web server on the Cloudfront side to know about its new name so that it will show the correct website to clients if the server is using vhosts.

I've never used Cloudfront, specifically, so I don't know any details about the setup.

Edit: Although now that I re-read your question I wonder if I might have misread what you want to do.

I think your current DNS record is something like:

```
www.example.com. 3600   IN     CNAME   example.com.
```

which means that when a browser asks for www.example.com it will find that the IP is the IP of example.com

If you instead configure your DNS for example.com with a CNAME record like

```
www.example.com. 3600   IN     CNAME   example1234.cloudfront.com.
```

Any DNS resolution requests for www.example.com will resolve to example1234.cloudfront.com.

However, I might have misunderstood your question and you want the other way around, in which case your current setup is something like:

```
example.com.     3600   IN     CNAME   www.example.com.
```

Then the new record should be

```
example.com.     3600   IN     CNAME   example1234.cloudfront.com.
```

Or you could do both:

```
www.example.com. 3600   IN     CNAME   example1234.cloudfront.com.
example.com.     3600   IN     CNAME   example1234.cloudfront.com.
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I will do some test after hour and post the results.

Comment: I only change the value of the CNAME www.example.com to example1234.cludfront.com and the CNAME of cloudfront to www.example.com and I was able to see my domain using cludfront. My only concern is that I start receiving alerts from Pingdom.com saying my domain was down, when it wasn't. So I suspect something is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand, did you change them so that they point to each other? i.e. creating an infinite DNS loop?

Answer (score 0):

change the CNAME of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to "example1234.cludfront.com" will simply fix your issue.